# Is it possible to run multiple of test in one unit in testng

Tags: selenium

I am reading data from excel and running my test cases.It is possible to run multiple of test method in one test unit using testNg and eclipse.Below is my code.I tried it but getting error

at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:161)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:429)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleParameters(Invoker.java:1383)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.createParameters(Invoker.java:1075)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1180)

**login.java**

```
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;

import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer;
import org.testng.annotations.*;

import java.io.File;

import jxl.*;

public class login extends SeleneseTestCase {

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        try {
            System.out.println("in setup");
            SeleniumServer seleniumserver = new SeleniumServer();
            seleniumserver.boot();
            seleniumserver.start();
            // String
            // firefoxPath="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe";

            setUp("http://localhost:8080/",
                    "*firefox C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");

            // selenium.open("/");
            selenium.windowMaximize();
            selenium.windowFocus();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "DP1")
    public Object[][] createData1() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("in createData1");
        Object[][] retObjArr = getTableArray(
                "test\\Resources\\Data\\logins.xls", "loginSheet", "Login");
        return (retObjArr);
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "DP1",testName="checkLogin")
    public void testLogin1(String userName, String Password,
            String expectedResult) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("in testLogin1");
        System.out.println("userName: " + userName + " Password: " + Password
                + " expectedResult: " + expectedResult);
        selenium.open("Banking/Login.jsp/");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        selenium.type("id=fname", userName);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        selenium.type("id=Lname", Password);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        selenium.click("name=sub");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        boolean res = selenium.isTextPresent(expectedResult);
        System.out.println("ver: " + res);
        verifyTrue(res);

        Thread.sleep(1000);

    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "DP1" ,testName="homepage")
    public void testLogin2(String userName, String Password,
            String expectedResult) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("in testLogin2");

    }

    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown() {
        selenium.close();
        selenium.stop();
    }

    /* this method read the data from excel sheet */

    public String[][] getTableArray(String xlFilePath, String sheetName,
            String tableTagName) throws Exception {
        String[][] tabArray = null;
        System.out.println("in getTableArray");

        System.out.println("table: " + tableTagName + " xlFilePath:"
                + xlFilePath + " sheetName: " + sheetName);
        Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(xlFilePath));
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
        int startRow, startCol, endRow, endCol, ci, cj;
        Cell tableStart = sheet.findCell(tableTagName);// find table name in
                                                        // excel
        startRow = tableStart.getRow();
        startCol = tableStart.getColumn();

        Cell tableEnd = sheet.findCell(tableTagName, startCol + 1,
                startRow + 1, 100, 64000, false);

        endRow = tableEnd.getRow();
        endCol = tableEnd.getColumn();
        System.out.println("startRow=" + startRow + ", endRow=" + endRow + ", "
                + "startCol=" + startCol + ", endCol=" + endCol);
        tabArray = new String[endRow - startRow - 1][endCol - startCol - 1];
        ci = 0;

        for (int i = startRow + 1; i < endRow; i++, ci++) {
            cj = 0;
            for (int j = startCol + 1; j < endCol; j++, cj++) {
                tabArray[ci][cj] = sheet.getCell(j, i).getContents();
                // System.out.println("tabArray: "+ tabArray[ci][cj]);
            }
        }

        return (tabArray);

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, you get an error because you didn't create `dataProvider` called "homepage".

I strongly advice to move your project to selenium 2. Selenium RC is not supported anymore (as far as I know). Selenium 2 contains a standalone server in simple library. You can find it under this [link](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.45/selenium-java-2.45.0.zip)

And answer to your question - yes it is possible to create 2x `@Test`. You can create multiple @Tests, group them, or set dependency on method. Everything is under this [link](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html).

Comment: Thanks for reply Rafal, actually I have dataprovider in same excelsheet.So I used same dataProvider in my code.Is this a wrong way??

Comment: Thanks for reply Rafal, actually I have dataprovider in same excelsheet.So I used same dataProvider in my code.Is this a wrong way?? Please see screenshoot of excelsheet [link](http://imgur.com/Xbz43JQ)

Comment: Hey Rafal thanks for help,i solved my error,I created data provider in my code add this code @Test(dataProvider = "DP2")
   public void testLogin2(String userName, String Password,
     String expectedResult) throws Exception {
// your code }